# Does _COOKIE info have only the cookies of the current Request

Tags: php, cookies

What does _COOKIE variable contain. Does it just contain the cookie that is sent by the browser for the current request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct!

[`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

> The value of $_COOKIE is determined by
>   the content of cookies received in the
>   user agent's request.

Answer (score 2):

**Contents of the $_COOKIE superglobal variable:**

When retrieving [**cookies with PHP**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) using the [**superglobal**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) [**$_COOKIE**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) an associative [**array**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of variables passed to the current script via HTTP Cookies is returned.

To inspect all the cookie variables simply use:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

To retrieve the value of a specific cookie variable, reference the key of the cookie variable:

```
echo $_COOKIE["myVariableName"];
```

The trickiest thing about retrieving cookies with PHP is that a cookie variable will not be available until the request after it is set. So **you cannot access a cookie with PHP until after the next page load**:

```
// Cannot have output before setting cookies. 
// Cookie will be sent along w the rest of the HTTP headers.
setcookie("name", "Pat");

// If the above was the first time "name" was set,
// this will echo NOTHING!!!
echo $_COOKIE["name"];

// You will only be able to retrieve $_COOKIE["name"] after the
// next page load.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pretty much on the dot...**

You basically use [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) to get the data stored in cookies from the browser

Of course **cookies** are not always very reliable, as **they can be turned off** by the client but nonetheless used widely.